# Determining the reason for a call termination on an Android phone

Tags: android

In a telephone call between two Android phones, is it possible to determine whether the call was dropped or was terminated by one of the phone users (i.e. someone pressed the "End Call" button)? In the latter case, can we determine which user ended the call?

Comment: That information is not available.

Comment: this is not possible !